# how to implement bootstrap themes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use startbootstrap themes to my rails application

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

I have download the themes extract it

move the css folder into vendor/stylesheets

move the javascript folder into vendor/javascripts

edit the index.html file and remove all the dependencies from there(remove the css and remove the javascript)

then

I edit my application.js and application.css to include the css and js files from the themes

```
application.js
//= require vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
//= require vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
//= require vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js
//= require vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
//= require js/creative.min.js

application.css
*= require vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
*= require vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
*= require vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css
*= require css/creative.min.css
```

the css and image is working properly but the javascripts never work Idk why

so far my workaround is copy all the files into public folder

Comment: You have "followed" a thousand questions and tutorials to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly install the bootstrap gem and install it.

Open your gemfile and put:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
```

bundle install.

Open your application.css and put:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Rename your application.css to application.scss

Open your application.js and put:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```